# How to show that the $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x+1)-f(x)=L$ when $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)=L$?

Tags: limits, derivatives

Suppose that f is differentiable on (0,$\infty$) and that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)=L$. Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x+1)-f(x)=L$.

I've been trying to do this proof. I tried substituting $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ for L in the equation and then trying the definition of the derivative, but that didn't lead anywhere. I'm thinking that I could use the definition of the derivative with the left side of the equation somehow, but I'm not sure where to start on that

Could I possibly get some guidance on where to go next with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the mean value theorem?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I was considering it. I tried using the fact that $f'(c)=(f(b)-f(a)/(b-a)$ and substituting that for f'(x) with b=x+1 and a=x. The right side would be $$f(x+1)-f(x)$$ but I'm unsure how to use that when the left side is a limit.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my issue of getting the right side in a limit.